# Solving of system of congruent residues

Tags: modular-arithmetic

let us suppose we have following two equation

$\rm\ y+8\equiv 4\pmod {11} $

$\rm\ y+8\equiv 7\pmod {11}$

for example  for the first  equation , we  can get following values of  $y$

$y=7, 18, 29$ for instance

for the second equation we can get following solutions

$y=10, 21, 32$

but  on one site , there  is given solutions like this

$\rm\ y\equiv 7\pmod {11} $

$\rm\ y\equiv 10\pmod {11} $

How can I  find it? Using Chinese remainder theorem  or?

Comment: add 3 to each side of the equation... and you'll discover that substracting X is the same than adding 11-X.

Comment: why 3?  for getting $11$ on the left part?

Comment: @dato datuashvili: is it possible that you have made a typo in your problem statement: we have that $4 \equiv y + 8 \equiv 7 \mod 11$ but $4$ is not congruent with $7$ $\mod 11$.

Comment: @Student these are 2 sets of equations.

Comment: @zwim: sorry, i was confused because of the title stating it is a system of equations.

Answer (score 0):

If the two equations are supposed to be a system of equations then there is no solutions.

If those two are separate equations just add $3$ to both sides to get the answer.

Comment: can you tell me  general rule  about this?

Comment: Well in the first case there is no solution because a number cannot be congruent to two different numbers when the modulus is same. And in the second it's just the fact that $11=0$ (mod $11$).

Comment: does this rule work  for any  similar case?

Comment: i will post one more question